# google Oauth 2.0 without using webview in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have requirement to access google calendar api using google Oauth 2.0 but I know how to do with webview using in appcelerator but google stopped webview support so I need google Oauth 2.0 without webview.

Any idea?

Comment: have you read the (very comprehensive) google documentation and free sample code on this topic? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: yeah i read but in titanium how it will work with out web view i am thing

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp ?? This says it's for mobile apps

Comment: for getting the google authKey you can use ti.googlesignin module https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-google-signin, https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.GoogleSignIn

for more modules please see https://github.com/appcelerator-forks

Comment: I used that module but how to call google calendar api if you don't mine  provide sample code after generating token